# Why is an unknown line being printed to stdout by sshtunnel module?

Tags: python, ssh, ssh-tunnel

If I run this code:

```
import sshtunnel

try:
    with sshtunnel.open_tunnel("hello", ssh_username="user",
                               ssh_password="PASSWORD",
                               remote_bind_address=("1.2.3.4", 23)) as server:
        pass
except:
    pass
```

I get this:

```
2016-04-06 10:47:53,006 | ERROR   | Could not resolve IP address for hello, aborting!
```

I am ignoring the exception, but some random line is showing up for some reason. Why? Is this just some random print statement in some library somewhere? Is this common? Seems like libraries shouldn't really be printing anything to the screen directly. How do I suppress this line?

PS. Code meant to simply replicate the error - obviously using a catch-all for exceptions and doing nothing with them is bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a logging statement, specifically `logging.error()`.

It's going to the screen because you haven't set up a log handler which would send it somewhere else.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html for more information.

It's going to the standard error output (which on a terminal window looks the same as the regular output.)  If your code were part of a web service, it would go to the web server's error log.

Comment: Simply setting up a log handler won't be enough. `sshtunnel` sets up a console logger if you don't pass one into the call. That's rather bizarre I think, but there it is.

Comment: Thanks for the info everyone - it really helped. The simplest way to suppress these lines appears to be to pass `debug_level=100` to open_tunnel, as default logging levels only go up to 50 for CRITICAL. I mainly use the exception itself, and its traceback to figure out what the error was, and where it happened - I will take a closer look into these logging features in python in case I actually need to use them in the future.

Comment: Upon further testing, `debug_level=100` has removed some messages from sshtunnel, but not all. I also tried passing sshtunnel `logger=logging.getLogger("test")`, or just including `logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log", level=logging.DEBUG)` at the top of my code, but neither prevents the logging messages from coming to the screen. `mute_exceptions=True` and `raise_exception_if_any_forwarder_have_a_problem=False` didn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 1):

The first non-keyword argument you pass to `open_tunnel` is expected to be the destination server (either a string, or an `(ip, port)` tuple (see the function's [docstring](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py#L1445)).

Eventually, this leads to `ssh_host` being set to `"hello"` in the example you gave, which logs an error message in [this except block](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py#L1042).

Answer (score 0):

The part where you have `"Hello"` should ideally have the IP address of the SSH Server that you are connecting to. The random line that you mentioned is the `ERROR` statement that explains it.

Although the program does not have any stdout statements, the ERROR line is from the library `sshtunnel`.

The statement block in the library uses a `raise(exeption)` statement with this particular error message. `raise` function is used to populate messages that can be captured by except statements.

Answer (score 0):

*"some random line is showing up for some reason."* - its a straight-forward error message... the remote server couldn't find a host called "hello". As for why you see it, `sshtunnel` creates a console logger for error messages if you don't pass a logger yourself. That is a strange thing to do, IMHO. `open_tunnel` accepts two keywoard arguments: `logger` is a standard python logger and `debug_level` is the level to log. See [python logging](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html) for details on setting up a logger.

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

add `threaded=False`

---

Hello I had exactly the same ERROR

and it appears after the closing of the tunnel (release):

```
2018-01-16 10:52:58,685| INFO    | Shutting down tunnel ('0.0.0.0', 33553)
2018-01-16 10:52:58,764| INFO    | Tunnel: 0.0.0.0:33553 <> sql_database_resolved_on_remote:1433 released
2018-01-16 10:52:58,767| ERROR   | Could not establish connection from ('127.0.0.1', 33553) to remote side of the tunnel
2018-01-16 10:52:58,889| DEBUG   | Transport is closed
```

That's somewhat normal, but why it's there?

### "Solution-ish"

Add `threaded=False`.

Both tested with `open_tunnel()` and `SSHTunnelForwarder` in `with ... as tunnel:` context:

```
import time
import socket
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder, open_tunnel

def test_tunnel(tunnel):
    # Wait for tunnel to be established ?
    #tunnel.check_tunnels()
    #time.sleep(0.5)
    #print tunnel.tunnel_is_up
    s = socket.socket()
    s.settimeout(2)
    for i in range(0, 10):
        """
        I create a new socket each time otherwise I get
        the error 106 (errno.EISCONN):
        'Transport endpoint is already connected'
        """
        s = socket.socket()
        s.settimeout(2)
        state = s.connect_ex(('localhost', tunnel.local_bind_port))
        s.close()
        okoko = "OK" if state == 0 else "NO"
        print "%s (%s)" % (okoko, state)

with open_tunnel(
    'server_i_can_ssh_with_mykey',
    ssh_username='myuser',
    ssh_pkey='/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa',
    ssh_private_key_password=None, #no pwd on my key
    remote_bind_address=('sql_database_resolved_on_remote', 1433), #e.g.
    debug_level=10, # remove this if you test with SSHTunnelForwarder
    threaded=False,
) as tunnel:
    test_tunnel(tunnel)
```

hth